# Why can't send email for rotated log info?

Tags: email, logging

I want logrotate to send rotated log info to my email `xxxx@yahoo.com`.

```
cat  /etc/logrotate.d/myservice.log

/var/log/myservice.log {
    size=1M
    dateext
    daily
    rotate 3
    compress
    delaycompress
    missingok
    notifempty
    echo | mutt -s "Log files for `date`"   xxxx@yahoo.com -a  /var/log/myservice.log
    create 644 root root
    postrotate
        /usr/bin/killall -HUP rsyslogd
    endscript
}
```

Why the rotated log info can't send to my yahoo mail box?

Comment: Why can't you respect the logrotate.conf syntax?  "echo" is not a logrotate directive.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
/var/log/myservice.log {
    size=1M
    dateext
    daily
    rotate 3
    compress
    delaycompress
    missingok
    notifempty
    create 644 root root
    postrotate
        /usr/bin/killall -HUP rsyslogd     
        /bin/echo | mutt -s "Log files for `date`"   xxxx@yahoo.com -a  /var/log/myservice.log
    endscript
}
```

You may need to specify the full path for "mutt", and adapt the name of the log, as Esa remarked, it can be log.1, perhaps log.1.gz.

BTW, rsyslogd is capable enough to handle log rotation itself, by calling a script you provide when rotation is needed.  You could add the mailing to your script.  eg. https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v8-stable/tutorials/log_rotation_fix_size.html, and I quote:

```
# start log rotation via outchannel
# outchannel definition
$outchannel log_rotation,/var/log/log_rotation.log, 52428800,/home/me/./log_rotation_script
#  activate the channel and log everything to it
*.* :omfile:$log_rotation
# end log rotation via outchannel
```

Comment: On the other hand, `postrotate` would send empty log now; `-a /var/log/myservice.log.1` might be more relevant.

Comment: I was only trying to reduce the spam ;-)